# Sql server - create dynamic string result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new with SQL and I have the following problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #Contracts(
    --[ContractsOb_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Contract_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Day] [int] NULL,
    [FromHour] [datetime] NULL,
    [ToHour] [datetime] NULL,
    [Program] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [FullDayYN] [bit] NULL,
    [NrHours] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DayName] [varchar](50) NULL,
   )


INSERT INTO #Contracts
           ([Contract_ID]
           ,[Day]
           ,[FromHour]
           ,[ToHour]
           --,[Program]
           ,[FullDayYN]
           ,[NrHours]
           ,[DayName])
     VALUES
                (6283,  1,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Monday'),
            (6283,  2,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Tuesday'),
            (6283,  3,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Wednesday'),
            (6283,  4,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 23:00:00.000',      0,  13.00,  'Thursday'),
            (6283,  6,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 23:30:00.000',      0,  13.50,  'Saturday'),
            (6283,  7,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Sunday'),
            (6288,  1,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Monday'),
            (6288,  2,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Tuesday'),
            (6288,  3,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  10.00,  'Wednesday'),
            (6288,  4,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  10.00,  'Thursday'),
            (6288,  5,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 23:30:00.000',      0,  13.50,  'Friday'),
            (6288,  6,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 23:30:00.000',      0,  10.50,  'Saturday'),
            (6288,  7,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Sunday'),
            (6289,  1,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Monday'),
            (6289,  2,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Tuesday'),
            (6289,  3,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  12.00,  'Wednesday'),
            (6289,  4,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  10.00,  'Thursday'),
            (6289,  5,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 23:30:00.000',      0,  10.00,  'Friday'),
            (6289,  6,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 23:30:00.000',      0,  10.00,  'Saturday'),
            (6289,  7,  '2016-06-01 10:00:00.000',  '2016-06-01 22:00:00.000',      0,  10.00,  'Sunday')

select * from #Contracts



select [Contract_ID],[NrHours],
Result= STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT distinct ',' + [DayName] 
                FROM #Contracts As T2
                WHERE T2.[Contract_ID] = TT.[Contract_ID] and tt.[NrHours]=T2.[NrHours] and t2.[NrHours] is not null
                order by ',' + [DayName]--T2.[Day] 
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        , 1, 1, '')
 from #Contracts TT
 group by [Contract_ID],[NrHours]
 having [Contract_ID]=6288 and [NrHours] is not null
 order by [Contract_ID]

drop table #Contracts
```

So, i need to make this dinamically, one row  for each contract_id:

- 6283 : M-W 10h ; Th - 13h ; Sat - 13.5h
- 6288 : M,T,S - 12h; W,Th - 10h ; F - 13.5h; Sat -10.5h
- 6289 : M-W - 12h ; Th-S - 10h

For each contract_id , grouped by the number of hours worked per day, i need to to get the related days .

Explanation:

- 6283 : M-W(there are 3 days in a row) 10h ; Th(only one day) - 13h ; Sat - 13.5h
- 6288 : M,T,S(more than to days and they are not consecutive) - 12h; W,Th(only two days- it doesnt matter that they are a row or not) - 10h ; F - 13.5h; Sat -10.5h

**Note: when the days are consecutive, like in contract 6289, i need to show 'FirstDay'-'LastDay' and the number of hours(at least 3 days in a row)

Comment: I edited it. Practically the result is group by the contract_id. If i have only consecutive days and more than two consecutive days with the same number of hours per day the result is: FirstDay -LastDay and the number of hours per day. M-monday,T-tuesday,W-Wednesday,Th-Thursday,F-Friday,Sat-Saturday,S-Sunday

Comment: This is homework question, right?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
select *
from 
(
select   Contract_ID,
         NrHours, 
         Result2,
         consecutiv,
         NrRows,
         Case when NrRows >2 and consecutiv = 'Y' then --SUBSTRING(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Result2,'1 - ',''),'2 - ',''),'3 - ',''),'4 - ',''),'5 - ',''),'6 - ',''),'7 - ',''),0,CHARINDEX(',',replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Result2,'1 - ',''),'2 - ',''),'3 - ',''),'4 - ',''),'5 - ',''),'6 - ',''),'7 - ',''),0))
                                                            left(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Result2,'1 - ',''),'2 - ',''),'3 - ',''),'4 - ',''),'5 - ',''),'6 - ',''),'7 - ',''),1)
                                                            + ' - ' +
                                                           RIGHT(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Result2,'1 - ',''),'2 - ',''),'3 - ',''),'4 - ',''),'5 - ',''),'6 - ',''),'7 - ',''),1)
                when NrRows >2 and consecutiv = 'N' then replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Result2,'1 - ',''),'2 - ',''),'3 - ',''),'4 - ',''),'5 - ',''),'6 - ',''),'7 - ','')
                else replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Result2,'1 - ',''),'2 - ',''),'3 - ',''),'4 - ',''),'5 - ',''),'6 - ',''),'7 - ','')
                end + ' - ' + cast(NrHours as varchar)  as Final 
    from (
        select [Contract_ID],[NrHours] 
        ,Result2= STUFF
                (
                    (
                        SELECT distinct ',' + cast(Day as varchar) + ' - ' + left([DayName],1) 
                        FROM #Contracts As T2
                        WHERE T2.[Contract_ID] = TT.[Contract_ID] and tt.[NrHours]=T2.[NrHours] and t2.[NrHours] is not null
                        order by ',' + cast(Day as varchar) + ' - ' + left([DayName],1)
                        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
                , 1, 1, '')
        ,CASE
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Day) /*or COUNT(*) for duplicates */ 
                =  1 + MAX(Day) - MIN(Day) THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END as Consecutiv --to find the consecutiv days
       ,Count(*) as NrRows --to count the number of days
         from #Contracts TT
         group by [Contract_ID],[NrHours]
         having /*[Contract_ID]=6283 and*/ [NrHours] is not null
    ) z
)y
```

I used the select in a scalar function and got the desired result.